# Error occurs in python for MCP2210

Tags: python

I tried to upload below program in Python for SPI communication with ad5592r.

```
handle0 = c_void_p(Mcp2210_OpenByIndex(vid, pid, index0, path0, 
byref(pathsize0)));
```

But I am getting some errors while running the program. Please help to sort this problem.

```
pgpioDir = c_ushort( 0x00000140)
ret_code=mcp2210.Mcp2210_GetGpioPinDir(handle0,pgpioDir)

if ret_code != 0: #E_SUCCESS
    print("Unexpected error code returned: ", errors_dict.get(ret_code, ret_code))


else:
    print('i')
    print ("MCP2210 #0 manufacturer descriptor is: ", pgpioDir.value)
    print('k')
```